# Restrict selection between paragraph

Tags: javascript, angular

I´m working in a web application using angular, one of the sections is document section where the user is gonna be able to select the text and highlight the text, i´m using `window.getSelection()` to extract the selected text and appended in to a `<mark>` tag to highlight the text, but one of the requirements is that the is user is not gonna be able to select text between paragraphs for example:

[image]

In the image there is a selection between paragraph is there any way to avoid this, or stop the selection when the user jump from one paragraph another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found small hack of how to do it, i attach some properties to the paragraph tag here i put the code.

```
<p oncut="return false" onpaste="return false"
onkeydown="if(event.metaKey) return true; return false;" contenteditable="true"
spellcheck="false" autocorrect="off">Text</p>
```

Using this the selection is not possible to select between elements.

Comment: that's an interesting solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could calculate a substring before attaching it to the mark.

Using a regex like `/\r?\n/` or something similar to keep only the first chunk of the copied text in both *NIX and Windows systems (user-agnostic, to some extent).

Comment: but in this case doesn´t prevent the user of make the selection from one paragraph to another